# When you link an image in html it leaves this blue hyperlink pixel in the bottom right?

Tags: html, css

i linked couple of images that i have been working on and this has happened before but i fixed it by making the hyperlink text color the same as the background but i can not do that this time since i have an image as my background.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because link has a underline, for fix:
css:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: i dont know how i didnt even think of that but thanks! what a stupid mistake on my part ! It worked !

Comment: @MohamedMansour you're welcome )